# How to solve constrained ode problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, algorithms, numerical-methods

Currently I'm facing question in which let's say I have 3 coupled eqn.
\begin{align}
x = f(x', z', y', t)   \\
y = f(x', y', z', t)    \\
z = f(x', y', z', t)    \\
\end{align}
There is initial condition $x(0)$, $x'(0)$ ... and so on for each co-ordinate, I can now solve for the path.

But I would like to solve solution such that I know final position $x(t_{\rm final})$, $y(t_{\rm final})$, $z(t_{\rm final})$, $x'(t_{\rm final}) =$ any, $y'(t_{\rm final}) =$ any, $z'(t_{\rm final}) =$ any. $x(0)$, $y(0)$, $z(0)$ are also known. I would like to solve this set of equation for $x'(0)$, $y'(0)$, $z'(0)$. Given that When $x =$some number, $y >$ some number.

Any set of curve should work.

I have no idea how to go about this question. I would like to know how this type of solution can be found. Any numeric algorithm or mention of general topic related to these types of problems would be immensely helpful.

Comment: If you only have first order equations, you can only satisfy one boundary condition for each variable. Whether or not you reach the end conditions is out of your control.

Comment: Are the equations really with the same $f$? Please compare the second and third, they are either redundant, forcing $y=z$ or contradictory. -- Any initial (or boundary) value problem can only have 3 initial (or boundary) conditions, Your formulation is either redundantly trivial or unclear. -- Note that an implicit system need not be solvable for the highest order derivatives. Then it has to be classified as differential-algebraic system of equations (DAE) with the appropriate restrictions on possible solutions and numerical solution methods.

Comment: Are the left hand sides $x,y,z$ or $x',y',z'$?

Comment: @LutzL Thanks I think that topic is good for this context